# Input no builder do Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublime-text-2, sublimerepl

Estou usando o Sublime Text para estudar python, mas ele não suporta `input`.

Ao rodar o seguinte código com o build do sublime:

```py
velocidade = int(input("Digite a velocidade: "))
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> Digite a velocidade: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/matheusbaumgart/Desktop/python/outros/blank.py", line 1, in 
> velocidade = int(input("Digite a velocidade: "))EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Alguém conhece uma boa solução para poder usar input direto no sublime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sugiro experimentar a ferramenta [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL). Com ela você pode criar uma aba para ser usada como entrada interativa para seu programa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605079/520779)

**Nota:** estou vendo que você está utilizando `input` e depois tentando converter para um `int`. Isso não é necessário. O [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) já lê o conteúdo como código Python, enquanto o [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) retorna-o como uma simples string (i.e. `input(prompt)` é equivalente a `eval(raw_input(prompt))`). Por razões de segurança, sugiro usar `raw_input` sempre que possível.

Comment: Obrigado, instalei aqui, só o que sinto falta é de um atalho para rodar o código atual, como estou estudando, preciso rodar ele várias vezes, teria algum? pesquisei se não encontrei. Para entrada interativa o terminal está servindo bem :)

Comment: Não conheço nenhum, a única alternativa que posso sugerir é colocar seu código numa função e executar essa função a partir do terminal. Veja o código [nessa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2249310/520779) para um exemplo (esse é um padrão muito usado na prática em programas Python).

Comment: @MatheusBaumgart se por rodar o código atual você quer dizer rodar a seleção ou a linha, veja essa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8648/como-executar-a-linha-atual-no-sublime-text-2-ou-ide-que-permita-execucao-da-l