# Como executar a linha atual no Sublime Text 2? Ou, IDE que permita execução da linha atual em Python

Tags: python, sublime-text-2, r

No [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) (IDE para [r](/questions/tagged/r)) é possível executar a linha atual em vez de todo o arquivo usando `ctrl` (ou `cmd`) + `enter`. Isso é muito útil para  quando você quer testar apenas um pedaço de código separado do resto do arquivo.

Eu comecei a usar recentemente o Sublime Text 2 com Python. Sei que é possível rodar o código diretamente do Sublime Text 2 com `cmd` + `b` ([mas eu tive primeiro de ajustar o arquivo python.sublime-build para que ele pudesse obter o caminho correto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8571/build-do-sublime-text-2-da-resultado-diferente-do-ipython-na-linha-de-comando/8640?noredirect=1#8640)).

Mas seria bom também ter a opção de executar apenas a linha atual em vez de todo o arquivo. É possível fazer isso?

Se não for possível no Sublime Text 2, existe outro IDE que faça isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível com o pacote [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), que permite rodar interpretadores de diversas linguagens dentro do próprio editor.

Abra um interpretador de Python (`Tools` > `SublimeREPL` > `Python` > `Python`) e um arquivo de código-fonte Python. Eu costumo usar duas colunas, deixando o código em uma e o interpretador em outra. Coloque o cursor sobre a linha que deseja executar e escolha `Tools` > `SublimeREPL` > `Eval in REPL` > `Lines` (ou pressione `ctrl` e `,` simultaneamente, então solte e depois aperte a tecla L minúscula). Pronto, a linha será executada no interpretador.

Esse procedimento não é tão conveniente porque o cursor não vai automaticamente para a próxima linha e porque há comandos e teclas de atalho diferentes para enviar a linha atual e o para enviar o texto selecionado. Para R, o pacote [Enhanced-R](https://github.com/randy3k/Enhanced-R) resolve esses problemas. Não sei se há algo parecido para Python.

Comment: Valeu, funcionou!  Agora, outro problema, o SublimeREPL está usando um outro Python (talvez o do Sublime Text 2) e não o Anaconda que tenho instalado. Como alterar o `path` dele (como tive que fazer no `build` do Sublime)?

Comment: Tenta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861176/how-do-i-setup-sublimerepl-with-anacondas-interpreter

Comment: Beleza, valeu! Vou trazer essa pergunta para SOPT também, acho que é importante documentar aqui, se quiser responder lá! Abs

Comment: Acho melhor você mesmo responder, porque eu não tenho usado Python no dia-a-dia e não cheguei a testar a resposta.

Comment: Beleza, estou tentando essa solução que você sugeriu, se funcionar coloco lá!